# deluge script - date comparison operator versus current date

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I wrote the following deluge script, whene I am comparing the date of joining of the employee with the current date but i get a NULL response

Date of joining looks like 20-Nov-1979

```
searchMap1 = Map();
searchMap1.put("searchField","Dateofjoining");
searchMap1.put("searchOperator",">");
searchMap1.put("searchText",now);
```

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get my response from the application support team (in this case it is the zoho suite)

```
searchMap1 = Map();
searchMap1.put("searchField","Dateofjoining");
searchMap1.put("searchOperator","After");
searchMap1.put("searchText",zoho.currentdate.toString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're comparing date strings it's easiest to print out both and then convert them to dates depending on their format:

```
info date_one; //output 20-01-2022
info date_two; //output 20/01/2022

if (date_one.toDate("dd-MM-yyyy") > date_two.toDate("dd/MM/yyyy")
    {
         //do this 
    }
```